# Nested If Statement with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

My code won't reach the "if" statement piece of my code - does not display error though

```
name = input("Name: ")
gender = input("Gender: (Male or Female) ").lower()
age = input("Age: ")
weight = input("Weight: ")
height = input("Height: ")
activity_level = input("Activity level on a scale of 1 to 5: ")

if gender == 'male':
    bmr = (66 + (6.3*int(weight)) + (12.9*int(height)) - (6.8*int(age)))
    if activity_level == 1:
        calorie = bmr * 1.2
    elif activity_level == 2:
        calorie = bmr * 1.375
    elif activity_level == 3:
        calorie = bmr * 1.55
    elif activity_level == 4:
        calorie = bmr * 1.725
    elif activity_level == 5:
        calorie = bmr * 1.9
        print(f"Hello {name}, you need to consume {calorie} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
elif gender == "female":
    bmr = (655 + (4.3*int(weight)) + (4.7*int(height)) - (4.7*int(age)))
    if activity_level == 1:
        calorie = bmr * 1.2
    elif activity_level == 2:
        calorie = bmr * 1.375
    elif activity_level == 3:
        calorie = bmr * 1.55
    elif activity_level == 4:
        calorie = bmr * 1.725
    elif activity_level == 5:
        calorie = bmr * 1.9
        print(f"Hello {name}, you need to consume {calorie} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
```

I expect the code to calculate calories needed based on if the user is a male or female, and their inputted activity level and then print out the statement

Comment: My code stops after all inputs are entered... when I change the indent of my print statements, it says that "calorie" cannot be defined.. do I need to put the print below each elif statement?

Comment: It is good practice to add an `else` after all the `elif`s

Comment: You can replace all this ifs by something like this: https://gist.github.com/dhilst/6a5dbc4c02169cbc42622c02000a1b2e. Usually I use a dict for 1x1 mapping of values, but in this case in particular you have consecutive indexes, so a list fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all those *if statements* via an input list, which will be processes using *List Comprehension*. I also create separate functions to handle all the sub actions.

```
def male_calorie_intake (name, age, weight, height, activity_level):
   bmr = (66 + (6.3 * int(weight)) + (12.9 * int(height)) - (6.8 * int(age)))

   # This list contains the activity level (1-5) and their associated multiplier
   activity_levels = [(1, 1.2), (2, 1.375), (3, 1.55), (4,1.725), (5, 1.9)]

   # This list comprehension takes the user's inputted activity_level
   # and compares this level to activity_levels slice x[0] (e.g. 1).
   # The output is the matching activity level and its associated multiplier
   current_activity_level = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in activity_levels if x[0] == int(activity_level)]
   if current_activity_level:

     # This list comprehension slices the multiplier from the
     # list current_activity_level
     bmr_multiplier = [x[1] for x in current_activity_level]

     # The slice containing the multiplier is passed to the
     # match function
     calorie = bmr * bmr_multiplier[0]
     return name, calorie

def female_calorie_intake (name, age, height, weight, activity_level):
  bmr = (655 + (4.3 * int(weight)) + (4.7 * int(height)) - (4.7 * int(age)))

  # This list contains the activity level (1-5) and their associated multiplier
  activity_levels = [(1, 1.2), (2, 1.375), (3, 1.55), (4,1.725), (5,1.9)]

  # This list comprehension takes the user's inputted activity_level
  # and compares this level to activity_levels slice x[0] (e.g. 1).
  # The output is the matching activity level and its associated multiplier
  current_activity_level = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in activity_levels if x[0] == int(activity_level)]

  if current_activity_level:

    # This list comprehension slices the multiplier from the
    # list current_activity_level
    bmr_multiplier = [x[1] for x in current_activity_level]

    # The slice containing the multiplier is passed to the
    # match function
    calorie = bmr * bmr_multiplier[0]
    return name, calorie

def obtain_input():
  name = input("Name: ")
  gender = input("Gender: (Male or Female) ").lower()
  age = input("Age: ")
  weight = input("Weight: ")
  height = input("Height: ")
  activity_level = input("Activity level on a scale of 1 to 5: ")
  return name, gender, age, weight, height, activity_level


input_data = obtain_input()
if input_data[1] == 'male':
  results = male_calorie_intake(input_data[0], input_data[2], input_data[3], input_data[4], input_data[5])
  print(f"Hello {results[0]}, you need to consume {results[1]} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
elif input_data[1] == 'female':
  results = female_calorie_intake(input_data[0], input_data[2], input_data[3], input_data[4], input_data[5])
  print (f"Hello {results[0]}, you need to consume {results[1]} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
```

Comment: Thank you! this is awesome... can you help me understand the lines below:                        activity_levels = [(1, 1.2), (2, 1.375), (3, 1.55), (4,1.725), (5, 1.9)]
   current_activity_level = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in activity_levels if x[0] == int(activity_level)]
   if current_activity_level:
     bmr_multiplier = [x[1] for x in current_activity_level]

Comment: @ZachDesgain  You're welcome.  I added comments to the code.  Let me know if you need more information about all the functions.  If you see any issues with the code please let me know.  IMHO replacing all those if statements is the best approach to your original problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's reaching it, you have have the print statement under the last 'elif' so it's not reaching that part. you need to unindent:

```
name = input("Name: ")
gender = input("Gender: (Male or Female) ").lower()
age = input("Age: ")
weight = input("Weight: ")
height = input("Height: ")
activity_level = int(input("Activity level on a scale of 1 to 5: "))

if gender == 'male':
    bmr = (66 + (6.3*int(weight)) + (12.9*int(height)) - (6.8*int(age)))
    if activity_level == 1:
        calorie = bmr * 1.2
    elif activity_level == 2:
        calorie = bmr * 1.375
    elif activity_level == 3:
        calorie = bmr * 1.55
    elif activity_level == 4:
        calorie = bmr * 1.725
    elif activity_level == 5:
        calorie = bmr * 1.9
    print(f"Hello {name}, you need to consume {calorie} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
elif gender == "female":
    bmr = (655 + (4.3*int(weight)) + (4.7*int(height)) - (4.7*int(age)))
    if activity_level == 1:
        calorie = bmr * 1.2
    elif activity_level == 2:
        calorie = bmr * 1.375
    elif activity_level == 3:
        calorie = bmr * 1.55
    elif activity_level == 4:
        calorie = bmr * 1.725
    elif activity_level == 5:
        calorie = bmr * 1.9
    print(f"Hello {name}, you need to consume {calorie} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
```

Comment: Thanks Anna, when i do that, it tells me that calorie is not defined: line 20, in <module>
    print(f"Hello {name}, you need to consume {calorie} calories/day to maintain your current weight")
NameError: name 'calorie' is not defined

Comment: you need to change the input of activity level to integer, otherwise it's a string, updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

input returns a string so:
`activity_level = input("Activity level on a scale of 1 to 5: ")`

`activity_level` is a string and in the if statements you compare string to ints like this:

`if activity_level == 1:`

so you need to cast the input to a int like this:

`activity_level = int(input("Activity level on a scale of 1 to 5: "))`

You are getting calories is not defined because the program never goes into any of the if or elif statements

you can define calories before this statement `if gender == 'male':` to `calorie = 0` that way you don't have to call `print(...)` under the elifs

Comment: THANK YOU! That solves one of the problems... The other is the placement of the print statements - Currently, it wont print unless I have activity level 5, if I un-indent, it wont recognize the variable "calorie"... is there anyway to do it so I don't have to have that Print statement under each elif?

Comment: That did it! Thank you Tyger!